# Unusually cool looking tab bar setup within a rootviewcontroller of a UISplitView

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, uitabbarcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

The ABC (Australian Broadcasting Corporation) [iView app for iPad](http://itunes.apple.com/au/app/australian-broadcasting-corporation/id376620068?mt=8), has great looking tab like setup within a rootViewController of a UISplitView.

[image]

The tabs named "Browse/Watch/Listen" are particularly interesting are they simulated or real tabs?

It's unlike any UITabBar I've seen around in iPad apps.

Does anyone know how something like that is possible?

Comment: The one at the top? It's UIToolbar with its style set to `UIBarStyleBlack`

Comment: Sorry wrong link, now updated ....see second screen shot are they tabs on a rootviewcontroller of a splitview?

Comment: The link doesn't work for me in the US app store. Maybe a screenshot would help

Comment: Hi mjisrawi, Dont use itunes, do you mean you can't load link in browser in US?

Comment: @JimZ the app is probably only available in the AU store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The round rect button in custom mode will be transparent and any png image will maintain in transparencies.

3 or more buttons with transparent images would be the way to go. A different color for when they are selected and your all set. You could also make them look like they are overlapping with images that continue the button next to it.

With the iOS devices it is more about appearance and less about the underlying functionality.

Comment: Thanks, Most precise answer in reproducing this effect

Answer (score 1):

This is a custom control, they made themselves from scratch.

Fortunately for you, you don't need to make it from scratch. :)

There's a lot of open source component that does just this, [just](http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/bhtabbar) [like](http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/slidingtabs) [these](http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/jmtabview) [ones](http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/jsscrollabletabbar).

Comment: Great answer, if one doesn't want to reinvent wheel and finds these useful, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Those tabs look and feel like 3 UIButtons. Notice how the UI highlight acts when touching the buttons, and the action is only triggered on touchUpInside.

The tab content is probably a UITableView which gets refreshed when switching tabs.